# Reading file contents of a website?

Tags: php

All I want to check is that if a image exists in the link. I load it into an iframe. It was working fine but it seems they have removed the image but a blank.gif still exits.

**NOTE: The link is a different domain**

I tried the following codes in vain:

```
<?php
  $varia  =   file_get_contents($url);
  echo $varia;
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r(get_headers($url));
?>
```

and

```
$variablee = get_data($url);
pr($variablee);
```

All I get in the output is:

**HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing**

I want to put the condition that if blank.gif exits......some condition else some other condition.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you get the 404 if you access this URL from an ordinary browser?

Comment: no...I dont. I can open the link

Comment: Even the get_headers function returns the response 200, but in the output I get as 'HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing'. So weird

Comment: Maybe you need to specify a user agent in the headers - I can't remember what `file_get_contents` uses, but try resetting it to something different. (IMO you should not set your robot to look like an ordinary browser, as server operators do have the right to block you).

Comment: Also, maybe you need session/cookie support for this image. If so, try Goutte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to test if an URI actual `is` an image, is to see what [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns. If it returns an `array`, it is an image :

```
function imageExists($uri) {
    $info = @getimagesize($uri);
    return is_array($info);
}

if (imageExists($uri)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$content = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($content !== false) {
    // FILE EXISTS
} else {
    // FILE NOT EXISTS
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
if(getimagesize($url))
{
  //image exist
}
else
{
  //image not exist
}
```